# Numpy arrays changing unexpectedly

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

```
SL = np.zeros((N+1))
DDB, SOYD, MACRS, MEX, book_value = SL, SL, SL, SL, SL
print("MEX: ",MEX)
book_value[0] = inv_fci
DDB[0] = 0
print("MEX: ",MEX)
SL[1:m+1] = inv_fci/m
print("MEX: ",MEX)
```

So I made a numpy array SL which was basically (N+1) zeros, and I assigned it to a bunch of other arrays: DDB, SOYD, MACRS, etc. 
The weird part is, after I have done something to SL, all the arrays change exactly the way SL changed. 
MEX, which wasn't touched, becomes exactly like SL ie an array with m entries, all equal to inv_fci (a predetermined double variable). 
After doing some tests, even the other arrays are changing when I change SL.

Why are these arrays changing when I change SL?

Comment: Because you've only made one array and assigned it to a bunch of different names. Read the following: https://nedbatchelder.com/text/names.html

Comment: Use the `np.array(SL)` constructor to make independent copies.

Comment: Or the `.copy()` method

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
DDB, SOYD, MACRS, MEX, book_value = SL, SL, SL, SL, SL
```

This makes `DDB`, `SOYD`, `MACRS`, `MEX` and `book_value` point to the same object. If that object is modified, then all of your variables will be pointing to the same modified object.

A possible solution would be to create copies of SL, and assign a different copy to each of your variables.

Answer (score 0):

I guess because you are simply assigning a reference and not copying it.

You could try with copy

https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.copy.html